How to display whole numbers instead of rounded values in Datadog widget (Sunburst chart)?
I am using Datadog to monitor the total number of calls per organization. In one of my widgets, I'm seeing a total count displayed as 4.5M, but I would like to display the exact whole number instead, like 4,500,001.
Is there any way to configure Datadog to display the full number instead of rounding it? Below is the JSON configuration for the widget I'm using:
{
    "title": "Total calls per org",
    "requests": [
        {
            "formulas": [
                {
                    "formula": "query1"
                }
            ],
            "queries": [
                {
                    "data_source": "metrics",
                    "name": "query1",
                    "query": "sum:vsorgs.increment.orgcall{$service} by {orgid}.as_count()",
                    "aggregator": "sum"
                }
            ],
            "response_format": "scalar",
            "sort": {
                "count": 500,
                "order_by": [
                    {
                        "type": "formula",
                        "index": 0,
                        "order": "desc"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "style": {
                "palette": "datadog16"
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "sunburst",
    "legend": {
        "type": "table"
    }
}


Any help on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
